# how to call useSelector Hook only when the data is available

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I am making a API call in useEffect Hook and then saving the data in redux store. From redux store I am storing data in my browser local storage by making a useSelector call to get data from redux store.

How to make useSelector to call only once the data is ready from API.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Navbar from "./Navbar";
import Footer from "./Footer";
import HomeMenu from './HomeMenu';
import { fetchingInPending, fetchingSuccess, fetchingFailed } from './HomeSlice';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

const Home = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      dispatch(fetchingInPending());
      const response = await fetch("https://localhost:44316/api/auth/getuser", {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        credentials: "include",
      });
      
      if(response.status === 200){
        const content = await response.json();
        dispatch(fetchingSuccess({name: content.name, role: content.role}));
      }
      else{
        dispatch(fetchingFailed());
      }
    })();
  },[]);

  localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(useSelector(state => state.userDetails)));


  const user = localStorage.getItem('user');

  console.log(user);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
    <h1>Home</h1>
    </React.Fragment>
)};
```

HomeSlice

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export const homeSlice = createSlice({
  name: "userDetails",
  initialState: {
    name: "",
    role: "",
    isLoading: false
  },
  reducers: {
    fetchingInPending: (state) => {
      state.isLoading = true;
    },
    fetchingSuccess: (state, action) => {
      state.name = action.payload.name;
      state.role = action.payload.role;
      state.isLoading = false;
      state.error = "";
    },
    fetchingFailed: (state, action) => {
      state.isLoading = false;
      state.error = action.payload.error;
    },
  },
});

export const { fetchingInPending, fetchingSuccess, fetchingFailed } = homeSlice.actions;

export default homeSlice.reducer;
```

On my browser console I am getting data after three calls.

[image]

Index.js contain:

```
Index.js code:

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './style/index.css';
import App from './App';
import { BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import store from './store';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: you can't conditionally calling hooks. [Read the rules here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html).  Instead, you can use ```optional chaining``` when you get the state on ```useSelector``` such: ```const user = useSelector(state => state.user?.name?.email)```. you can read about the [optional chaining here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining).

Comment: I tried your code. I did not find any issue..I think this issue is not happening because of useSelector.  please check index.js. Your screenshot depicts issue is in index.js..  please post your index.js code.

Comment: updated with index.js code

Comment: It makes sense. There are three states: initial state, pending state, fulfilled state/rejected state. You can render different things based on these states. So, what do you want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think @slideshowp2 is correct, but for incorrect reasoning. There are no asynchronous actions being dispatched (i.e. thunks or similar), so there are no returned Promises to be fulfilled.

Your code

1. Logs the initial state
2. Logs the state after `dispatch(fetchingInPending());`
3. Logs the third state update after `dispatch(fetchingSuccess({ name: content.name, role: content.role }));`

You can't conditionally call React hooks, so your code is correctly persisting each state update to localStorage.

If you want to conditionally persist data to localStorage then place that logic in another `useEffect` hook with a dependency on the redux state. The condition is ensuring that the values from your redux store have been populated.

```
const userDetails = useSelector(state => state.userDetails);

...

useEffect(() => {
  const { name, role } = userDetails;
  if (name && role) {
    localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify({ name, role }));
  }
}, [userDetails]);
```

Alternatively you can just apply the localStorage persistence right in the existing `useEffect`. Here you persist to localStorage only when also dispatching the success action

```
useEffect(() => {
  (async () => {
    dispatch(fetchingInPending());
    const response = await fetch("https://localhost:44316/api/auth/getuser", {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      credentials: "include",
    });
  
    if(response.status === 200){
      const { name, role } = await response.json();
      const userDetails = { name, role };

      dispatch(fetchingSuccess(userDetails)); // <-- dispatch user details
      localStorage.setItem(                   // <-- persist user details
        'user',
        JSON.stringify(userDetails)
      );
    }
    else{
      dispatch(fetchingFailed());
    }
  })();
},[]);
```